# How to select a component on jframe?

Tags: jframe, jtextarea

How to select a `JTextArea` on `JButton` click?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    jTextArea1.setEditable(true);
    jTextArea1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    //*******************************************************
    jframe.setselected(jTextArea1); // I need such function!
    //*******************************************************

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By select I assume you mean transfer focus to the JTextArea. If so you can request focus of you text area with the following.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

jTextArea1.setEditable(true);
jTextArea1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

/*******************************************************
jTextArea1.requestFocusInWindow();
/*******************************************************
}
```